# What is valnurabilities and how can i fix them on angular

Tags: angular, npm, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ng

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9P4Y.png)

Hi everyone ,
I got this error code when i am trying to install bootstrap on my project with this code `npm install --saved bootstrap`. Could you help with simple language :pray:

Comment: The solution is to not use the faulty package in your app.

Comment: These aren't faulty packages. They have security vulnerabilities. Maybe you used an old package version.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the npm documentation for your issue](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit)

You may use an old project or installed an old version of a npm package. That's why you are seeing this warning in the terminal.

With `npm audit` you see the vulnerabilities.
Just run `npm audit fix` to fix all issues. If that doesn't work please fix your packages manually.